# Running a test using Shims on a Visual Studio 2013 Test Agent

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-fakes

I have found various iterations of this question across a number of websites, however so far I have not found anything that provides a full answer that worked.
I have just set up a number of Visual Studio Test Agents that all appear to be behaving and running most of the unit tests we are planning on initially running on them. However when I came to checking one of the unit tests it is failing on the line:
`using (ShimsContext.Create())`,
With the stack trace:

`Result Message:

Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException: Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH and COR_PROFILER environment variables.`


Having read some other posts I installed Visual Studio 2013 on the test agent and confirmed it would run the test locally. I then set COR_PROFILER_PATH to the profiler that was being used on my machine which was installed at: “C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\12.0.0\Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Profiler.12.0.0.dll”.
It then failed in the same place with the trace:

`Test method threw exception: 

Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException: Failed to get profiler module handle 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\12.0.0\Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Profiler.12.0.0.dll'. The specified module could not be found ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified module could not be found`



The suggestion is the profiler has been loaded under a separate process and can't be used. Has anyone had any success with this or similar set ups? At a fundamental level can Visual Studio Test Agents run tests with Fakes?
Thanks

Comment: Try to make your question a bit more laconic, since it's too big.

Comment: Is your OS 32-bit? If not you probably need to use "program files (x86)" instead of "program files".

Comment: No the file referenced does exist. The machine being used as a test agent is running Windows 7 Embedded 32bit.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a bit old, so the OP probably got his answer, but for anyone else, I opened a ticket with Microsoft on this issue, and the answer we came to after an hour and a half of looking at my setup for this problem:

Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException: Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH and COR_PROFILER environment variables.

, was that I was using **[mstest.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx)** and I should have been using **[vstest.console.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx)**.  In my case it was because I have Fakes test in my code now.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 update 4.

Comment: I have a post https://mfreidge.wordpress.com/2016/04/30/replace-mstest-to-vstest-to-support-fakes/ describing how to switch from MSTest to VStest

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with a project I was working on. I found this issue noted:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/832744/unable-to-debug-shims-based-tests-unittestisolation-exception

There was an attached project, so I downloaded the project and ran the only unit test. Same error - the unit test was not successful. However, I right-clicked on `System` under the `References`, and clicked `Add Fakes Assembly`. Once it had generated the fakes for `System` and `mscorlib`, voila! The test turned green.

I was able to reproduce the issue in my project - **I did not have fakes being generated for System. Once I generated them for System, my tests went from red to green!**

Side note -- If you don't want to generate ALL of the fakes for System and mscorlib, you can modify the .fakes files like so.

mscorlib.fakes:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="mscorlib" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
  <StubGeneration Disable="true" />
  <ShimGeneration Disable="true" />
</Fakes>
```

System.fakes:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="System" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
  <StubGeneration Disable="true" />  
</Fakes>
```

I could not disable ShimGeneration for System.fakes - the test would fail.

I hope this fixes the problem for someone else - the error is extremely vague!

Comment: Thanks  for   `StubGeneration Disable="true" `

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming your Test Agent is also a Build Agent.)

Is the build service version synced with the Visual Studio version which is installed?

I had the same issue in the following environment:

- TFS 2013
- Build Server w/ TFS 2013
- Visual Studio 2015.3 installed in the build server

When I updated the TFS version on the build server to 2015.3, the issue stopped happening.

I know it may not make sense, but solved the problem as the TFS 2015 XAML Build is compatible with TFS 2013.4 app tier.